# how call two procedure at a time from a single php page using MVC Architecture?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to call  two procedures which are created in MySQL and that return records in a PHP file. I am not able to call a procedure one after another. If I call one procedure after another procedure (from single PHP page), the second procedure will not return any records.

Even if I execute a `select` stament  which returns records after a procedure (which returns records) means `select` statement will not return any values. Why this is happening? How can we call two procedures one after another in a single PHP page?

Hi I am adding my Code Here...

model.php file content

```
<?php 
class DBoperation {
    function connect(){     
        $this->con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');    
        mysql_select_db('test',$this->con);     
    }  

    function call proc2($empcode){
        $this->sql="call proc1('$empcode',@strGrpId,@strTodate,@strAccPrTodt,@strRecalculate)";
    }

    function callproc2($strEmpCode){  
        $this->sql="call proc2('$strEmpCode',@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)";  
    }

    function execute(){
        $res = mysql_query($this->sql);
        return $res;
    }
}
?>
```

view.php file content

```
<?php 
require_once('../../model/model.php'); 
$empcode = $_SESSION['empcode'];
$obj=new DBoperation(); 
$obj->connect();
//calling first procedure 
$obj->callproc1($empcode);
$res = $obj->execute(); 
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $result[0]; 
} 
//calling second procedure
$obj->callproc2($empcode); 
$fetch=$obj->execute();
while($fetch1=mysql_fetch_array($fetch)){
    echo $fetch1[0]; 
}
?>
```

second procdure returns nothing. if i execute any select queries after second procdeure also i wont return anything.

Comment: How exactly do you call the two procedures? Could you show us the PHP code of the part where you call the procedures?

Comment: I have added my Code..Please go through it...

Comment: Are you sure your queries are correct? Try using `$res = mysql_query($this->sql) or die(mysql_error());` to get some output if a query fails.

Comment: ya. i am sure that my queries are correct. everything works fine. if i call the second procdure before first procedure means first procedure wont return any thing. even if i write a function which returns record after the one procedure(which returns records) means it wont return anything...

Comment: And if you try it without the `DBoperation` class? Just connect and use `mysql_query()` in test.php?

Comment: same result.. i have to use DB opration class..

Comment: I tried your code; I got a syntax error: your function is named `call proc2`. That should probably be `callproc1`. Also; you say that the first file is named "model.php", but you require "empModel.php". After I fixed the syntax error it worked like expected.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you. while adding code block i have changed empmodel to "model.php". that is why error came. i am facing this same issue in so many places while doing my project. what should be done to resolve this?

Comment: which version of PHP and MySQL do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <?php    
// New Connection

$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pwd','Dbname');

// Check for errors

if(mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo mysqli_connect_error();

}

// 1st Query

$result = $db->query("call proc1($empcode)");

   if($result)

     {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())

             {
              echo $col1="$row->Column Name1"."<br>";
              echo $col2="$row->Column Name2"."<br>";
             }

             // Free result set
             $result->close();
             $db->next_result();
     }


    // 2nd Query
    $result = $db->query("call proc2('$empcode')");
    if($result)   

    {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())

               {
                echo $col1="$row->Column Name1"."<br>";
                echo $col2="$row->Column Name2"."<br>";
               }

               // Free result set
               $result->close();
               $db->next_result();
    }
          else echo($db->error);

        // Close connection
         $db->close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put  `$db->next_result();` after execute first procured.